# Get value from Database to Linq where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table called `FILTRE_LINKLER` and column's names are

1. ID
2. SEF_URL
3. CONDITIONS

For example,

- ID=1
- SEF_URL="test/"
- CONDITIONS="STOCK>50"`

I want to get CONDITIONS part to linq where clause.

```
var product = (from d in db.PRODUCTS
                       where *CONDITIONS from DB*
                       select new ProductModel
                       {
                           Description= d.DESCRIPTION,
                           Brand= d.BRANDS.BRAND,
                           SefUrl = sef_url,
                           Name= d.NAME,

                       });
```

I try to that:

```
var query = db.FILTRE_LINKLER.Select(x => x.CONDITIONS);
 var product = (from d in db.PRODUCTS
                       where query
                       select new ProductModel
                       {
                           Description= d.DESCRIPTION,
                           Brand= d.BRANDS.BRAND,
                           SefUrl = sef_url,
                           Name= d.NAME,

                       });
```

But I have an error that is Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to bool.

I edited because "Problem Solved".
For solution:

Download Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic -Version 1.0.7 (said me @StepUp)
then add to class

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

then following code like that,

```
 var whereCondition = db.FILTRE_LINKLER.Select(x => x.CONDITIONS).FirstOrDefault();
var product = (from d in db.PRODUCTS
                       where query
                       select new ProductModel
                       {
                           Description= d.DESCRIPTION,
                           Brand= d.BRANDS.BRAND,
                           SefUrl = sef_url,
                           Name= d.NAME,

                       }).Where(whereCondition);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add conditions dynamically? Use the extension methods instead of the query syntax and pass whatever condition you want in the `.Where()` call. eg `if (useColor) { query=query.Where(product=>product.Color='Red'); }`

Comment: where this `STOCK` comes from in your `CONDITIONS`?

Comment: Yes, I want to add dynamically but it must come from Database because Conditions can change. It depends on Customers. One of them want to Stock>50 and others want to productName='test'. I want to write a code general usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try to use `Dynamic LINQ`](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library). This is a sample of code using `Dynamic LINQ` library:

```
var query = northwind.Products
                         .Where("CategoryID = 3 AND UnitPrice > 3")
                         .OrderBy("SupplierID");
```

In your case:

```
var whereCondition = db.FILTRE_LINKLER.Select(x => x.CONDITIONS).FirstOrDefault();
var product = (from d in db.PRODUCTS
                   select new ProductModel
                   {
                       Description= d.DESCRIPTION,
                       Brand= d.BRANDS.BRAND,
                       SefUrl = sef_url,
                       Name= d.NAME,

                   })
              .Where(whereCondition);
```

**UPDATE:**

1. At first you should download a code to use `Dynamic queries` [by this link](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqcsharp.zip).
2. Then use `DynamicQueryable` class from the project `Dynamic Query`
3. Then use your dynamic queries with `IQueryable<T>`.

Let me show an example:

```
var persons = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person(){Id = 1, FirstName = "1"},
    new Person(){Id = 2, FirstName = "2"},
    new Person(){Id = 3, FirstName = "3"}
};
var personWithIdTwo = persons
   .AsQueryable()
   .Where("Id==2");
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If you do not want to add class, [then you can use an `Expression Tree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).

An example of an expression tree:

```
var propName = "STOCK"; // here you assign any value
var constValue = "50";  // here you assign any value
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductModel), "p");
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductModel, bool>>(
    Expression.GreaterThan(
       Expression.Property(param, propName),
       Expression.Constant(constValue)
    ),
    param
);
var product = (from d in db.PRODUCTS
                   where query
                   select new ProductModel
                   {
                       Description= d.DESCRIPTION,
                       Brand= d.BRANDS.BRAND,
                       SefUrl = sef_url,
                       Name= d.NAME,

                   }).Where(exp);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

You can download library `Dynamic query` through NuGet. So you should not create classes in your project:

[image]

Comment: did not work. "cannot convert from system.linq.expressions.expression to system.func<Model,bool>" error messages I got.

Comment: @AnilSengul Please, see my updated answer. You should create class to work with dynamic queries.

Comment: Just I want to add little thing. I have to add class for little thing. Are there other way to do this ?

Comment: Property and Constant must be dynamic. These are in same string

Comment: @AnilSengul it is just an example. You should put them as parameter. Please, see my updated answer. Anyway in your case, it is simplier to use already written solution for you and just add this class.

Comment: How can I use string in Expression.Lambda? Like :

string whereCondition = db.FILTRE_LINKLER.Select(x => x.KOSUL).FirstOrDefault();

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305382/6879114

Comment: I asked you because you can know the answer. But sorry for that

Comment: Yes it is enough for me. Problem solved. Thanks for answering.
I shared solution above with editting my question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is to dynamically convert the conditions present in the database to where in linq. While there is no magic statement, that says use this. You would have to write an extension that is able to intrepret the conditions written in your database and returns a predicate which you could then use in your where clause.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: @AnilSengul you can pick some ideas from this article - https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq